# Why webkit browsers alerts css left position value as "auto" while value is set to "0px"

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/hQCS4/).

**CODE:**

```
alert( "slide-panel2 position: " + $('#slide-panel2').css("left") )
```

**CSS:**

```
#slide-panel2 { left: 0px; }
```

Why do WebKit browsers alert css `left position` value as `auto` when the actual value is set to `0px`?

In Firefox and IE it alerts `0px` as expected.

**EDITED:**

As **Alex** Stated in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12243821/1516616) below (And I am agree with him):

> Because your element has position: static (by default), so it will ignore the left property in regard to its layout. The browser only cares about left (and its friends) if your position property is set to absolute, relative or fixed.
>
> Changing it to position: relative gives the expected result.

But according to [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position):

> The `position` CSS property has default value `static`
>
> And in `static` The top, right, bottom, and left properties do not apply.

Then why does the alert show `0px` in Firefox and IE and `auto` in WebKit browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your element has `position: static` (by default), so it will ignore the `left` property in regard to its layout. The browser only cares about `left` (and its friends) if your `position` property is set to `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed`.

Changing it to `position: relative` gives the expected result.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4kDn/).

> Then why alert shows `0px` in Mozilla and IE and `auto` in WebKit browsers?

Because browsers have different implementations which don't necessarily agree. Even the browsers that show `0px` still treat it like it's `auto`.

Comment: I got your point,but why it is showing fine in IE, and Firefox? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @A.K Because browsers implement things differently.

Comment: According to these references: [ref1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) [ref2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531140(v=vs.85).aspx) `static` is default value of position in Mozilla and IE also.